# Google Maps API Direction, out of route

Tags: api, google-maps, routes, maps, directions

I use the Direction API to plot and save a route between A and B. 
My application receives a coordinated car gps, I would like to 
identify if the car is off course previously traced. 
Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may create a polyline based on the route and use [`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge) to check if the current coordinate is placed on/near the polyline.

For an approximate result create the polyline using the `overview_path` of the route, for higher accuracy use the `lat_lngs` of the `steps` of the route

Comment: Thank you, this really works but I need to do the same in the backend. Is it possible?